# How to convert reactive ClientResponse to String?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How can I convert a `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse` to `String`, if not as follows?

```
private static ExchangeFilterFunction errorHandler() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        if (someErrorCondition) {
            LOG.error("error rsp: " + clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
        }

        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
}
```

Result;:

> d.s.y.w.c.e.WebExceptionHandler: Output class [java.lang.String] is
>   neither annotated with @XmlRootElement nor @XmlType

Comment: It seems you somewhere declared that your expected response is xml. Deserializer (probably JAXB) tries to deserialize structured object written in xml as `String`, which is not structured (and is missing some required annotations too). 
By the way, you won't be able to print response this way. `clientResponse.bodyToMono` returns `Mono`, not the actual data contained in it (because returning data would involve blocking). You will have to use something like `bodyToMono.doOnNext(s -> {if(condition) log.error(s);}`